Memory Leak with AVPlayer - Bug or Implementation Issue?
I've been working on an audio player project and recently discovered a memory leak. After spending several days debugging without success, I decided to create a simplified project using AVPlayer to analyze the issue further.
`
import SwiftUI
import AVKit


struct ContentView: View { @State private var player: AVPlayer? = nil
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Audio Player")
            .font(.title)
            .padding()

        if player != nil {
            Button(action: {
                if player?.timeControlStatus == .playing {
                    player?.pause()
                } else {
                    player?.play()
                }
            }) {
                Text(player?.timeControlStatus == .playing ? "Pause" : "Play")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        } else {
            Text("Loading Audio...")
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        let url = URL(string: "https://d12wklypp119aj.cloudfront.net/track/86d38d9a-2f4b-44ae-a77f-a72e034f6d54.mp3")!
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    }
    .onDisappear {
        player?.pause()
    }
}
}

Interestingly, I found that even this smaller project is experiencing memory leaks! Now, I'm wondering if this is a bug with AVPlayer, or if there's something wrong with my implementation.
Has anyone else encountered similar issues with AVPlayer? What steps would you recommend for identifying and fixing the leak?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
enter image description here
enter image description here

AVPlayer is a reference type that isn’t designed to work with State. You should put it inside an Observable class

@loremipsum Even that does not fix the problem. Did you try it and it worked out for you???? + I would have had a swiftui leak, not malloc
